# Haskell: parsing PDF

Tags: pdf, haskell

What I need is to read pdf, make some transformations (generate TOC bookmarks) and write it back.

I found this http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HPDF , but it only mentions generating pdf, not the parsing (although I could have missed it)

Haskell is chosen purely for (self)educational purposes.

Comment: Before you can even guess how much work is involved in writing a PDF parser you have to buy the ISO spec for CHF380 (about £243 or $353).  I suspect this puts people off.

Comment: Somehow it does not seem to stop ruby/perl people for instance.

Comment: You can download a free company of the PDF spec from Adobe's website: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html They host an unofficial version of the ISO spec, but the contents are exactly the same.

Comment: It sounds like they want it to be official AND unofficial:  " **This document is an ISO approved copy of the ISO 32000-1 Standards document.** By agreement with ISO, Adobe Systems Incorporated is allowed to offer this version of the ISO standard as a free PDF file on their own Web site. **It is not an official ISO document but the technical content is identical; the page and section numbers are also preserved** ."  Hah.  Pick one.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few tools for PDF manipulation, though they seem to bias towards generation, rather than parsing:

- http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

Pandoc is a great cross-markup library, but doesn't support PDF parsing (it does support PDF generation from a variety of formats).

There's also:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsHaruPDF
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdf2line -- tool for extracting text from pdf
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HPDF -- another pdf generation library

I'm not sure we have a good parsing tool yet.

Answer (score 3):

Also as a learning exercise, I started a PDF parsing library in Haskell, but it's incomplete and has been languishing a bit from lack of attention.  I'd be happy to share it with you, and would love feedback, improvements, etc.  It's not currently hosted on hackage, but if you're interested in working with an incomplete implementation, let me know and I'll ask some colleagues for advice on getting it up there.

Comment: I am far too junior for such a quest. But thanks anyway, I'll keep this in mind for future.

Comment: I'd be happy to work with you on it.  Its current state is that it takes a PDF file and produces an AST-like representation, which can be manipulated.  I've also got an AST pretty-printer that produces a valid PDF file.

Comment: Also, I can't seem to comment on the "waah, the PDF ISO spec is expensive", but I found the free documents here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/ to be sufficient for my PDF parsing needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a haskell binding to parts of xpdf:
  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdf2line

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [pdf-toolbox](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdf-toolbox-document) library. It's support for PDF file generating is [low level](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdf-toolbox-core-0.0.4.0/docs/Pdf-Toolbox-Core-Writer.html), but powerful enough for your task.

[Here](https://github.com/Yuras/pdf-toolbox/blob/stable/examples/change-document-title.hs) is an example how to change title of an existing PDF file using incremental update feature.

Answer (score 1):

Another package to consider is [**rakhana**](https://github.com/YoEight/rakhana/blob/master/examples/Simple.hs) which is also [on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rakhana).